# Using Smo in C# - skip constraint generating instructions at the beginning

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

I have to create a full copy of a remote db. I have only one useful and easy way to do it: by generating scripts. I am aware about other ways (create backup, for instance) but I can't use them for some reason.

Since one table might be depend on another (has a foreign key, etc...) and because of this it's pretty difficult to figure out the valid order of creating tables, I decide to generate these "dependable" script instructions at the very end.

Well, I know how to generate that "dependable" script instructions within (close to) table creation. But what should I do to skip them first only to generate them at the end?

For instance:

```
--How I do NOT want
--.........................
CREATE TABLE Table1(....)
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT ...

CREATE TABLE Table2(....)
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD CONSTRAINT ...



--How I would like
--.........................
CREATE TABLE Table1(....)
CREATE TABLE Table2(....)
--.........................
CREATE TABLE TableN(....)
--.........................
--the end of a script
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you have code that already loops through the tables and calls the `Script()` method on each table. What you're going to want to do is create a [ScriptingOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions_properties.aspx) object, set its DriForeignKeys property to false, and call the `Script()` method with that ScriptingOptions object as a parameter. Then, once you've looped through all of the tables, you're going to need to do it again, this time to pick up the foreign keys.

Comment: When I'm going to do it again, how could I pick up **only** foreign keys script instructions without tables' script ones?

Comment: The Table object has a ForeignKeys property. Iterate through that collection for each table and script out each one.